# O que é microprogramação?

Tags: ciência-da-computação, linguagem-de-máquina

- O que é microprogramação?
- Qual a importância dela?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Microprogramação

**Microprogramação:** método alternativo para gerar os sinais de controle de maneira sistemática e ordenada. É programar de forma estratégica a unidade de controle de um processador a nível de operações. Uma memória de controle armazena sequências de códigos binários que disparam apropriadamente os sinais de controle que executam determinadas micro operações.

**Microprograma:** sequência de microinstruções cuja execução corresponde a uma instrução de máquina.

- Para cada instrução de máquina, há um microprograma específico que indica todas as microoperações necessárias para sua execução.
- Executar um microprograma, portanto, tem o mesmo efeito que executar uma instrução de máquina.

**Arquitetura:** Instruções CISC típicas setam "*condition codes*", o que demanda tempo de execução, além do fato de os programadores terem um esforço extra em lembrar de examina-las.

---

#### Diferença entre Microprogramação e Linguagem de Máquina

Linguagem de Máquina, também é conhecida como Assembly, que significa, exatamente o que esta escrito. É a forma que uma CPU ou um microcontrolador utiliza para se comunicar com seus periféricos (binário), regida pelo microprograma.

O microcódigo, é uma camada de hardware em nível de instruções, envolvidos na implementação da linguagem de maquina dos processadores. Reside em memória especial, de alta velocidade e traduz instruções de maquina em sequencias de operações a nível de circuitos.

Microcódigo é muitas vezes chamado de microprogramação e o microcódigo na implementação de um processador em particular é chamado de microprograma.

Assim como **Assembly** é diferente de **Assembler**:

- Que é o compilador que converte o Assembly para linguagem da máquina.

---

#### Referência e mais informações:

- Prof. Léo Pini e pelo aluno de doutorado Tiago Novaes
- [http://www.dca.fee.unicamp.br/~leopini/DISCIPLINAS/EA869/2018-1/g1-microprogramacao.pdf](http://www.dca.fee.unicamp.br/%7Eleopini/DISCIPLINAS/EA869/2018-1/g1-microprogramacao.pdf)
- http://www.hamer.com.br/arq/conceitos.htm
- https://www.clubedohardware.com.br/forums/topic/962792-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-microprograma%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-linguagem-de-m%C3%A1quina/

Comment: Desculpa, mas acho que a resposta está meio confusa, ao invés de sair colando trechos de outros sites eu acho que seria melhor você fazer uma resposta com suas palavras ou tentar conectar os trechos dos sites de maneira que fique mais clara a resposta

Comment: Ajustei a resposta com menos detalhes técnicos e explicando o que é a microprogramação, basicamente ela está a nível de operações em uma camada de baixo nível próximo à linguagem de máquina.

Comment: @OutOfM3mory Obrigado pelo seu voto. Abraço!